# jflap duplicating states or transitions

Tags: turing-machines, jflap

I was wondering if there was a way we could "copy" and "paste" states/transitions in jflap? For example take the following one:[image]

Say I wanted to duplicate the transition from  q1->q2 for q2->q3, is there an easy way to do this?
Thanks in advance.